# How to check streaming data record already there in historical/persisted data in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, datastax

For my PoC, I am using spark-sql 2.4.x with Kafka.
I have a streaming company data coming from Kafka topic. 
Company data Which has "company_id" ,"created_date" ,"field1" , "field2" and etc as fields. lets say this as newCompanyDataStream.

I have old company data in my parquet file. i.e. "hdfs://parquet/company" , lets say this as oldCompanyDataDf.

> I need to check the new data stream from kafka (newCompanyDataStream)
>   , for each received record of  given company_id , if the data already
>   there in the "hdfs://parquet/company" file. (oldCompanyDataDf)

**How to check this?**

> If newCompanyDataStream "field1" and  oldCompanyDataDf "field1"  not
>   same then perform tast2 ( i.e. removed oldCompanyDataDf record and add
>   newCompanyDataStream "field1" record into oldCompanyDataDf )
>
> If newCompanyDataStream "field2" and  oldCompanyDataDf "field2"  not
>   same then perform tast2 ( i.e. removed oldCompanyDataDf record and add
>   newCompanyDataStream "field2" record into oldCompanyDataDf )

**How to implement this using spark-sql structured streaming?**

For Any snippet or advice is very much thankful

Comment: Have you tried `join` of a streaming and a batch Datasets?

Comment: Show the code. Edit your question and show what you've got so far.